# Solving a Paradox Involving Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

So I encountered an exercise in my algebra textbook and it is somewhat paradoxical. Here is the exercise:

$$1 = \sqrt{1} =\sqrt {(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{(-1)} \sqrt{(-1)} = i^2 = -1$$

I think it has to do with the first step of the problem. The number $\sqrt{1}$ shouldn't simplify to just 1. Is it possible that $\sqrt{1}$ can also be $± 1$?

Edit: I wasn't aware that someone else had already asked a similar question to what I just asked.

Comment: you cant split the roots when numbers inside are negative

Comment: Yes that is what Arnold said you both are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$$

That is true only if $a\ge 0$ and $b\ge 0$.

Comment: I see. So the middle part of the string of inequalities is false then?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong!

Comment: Okay now it makes sense! I knew it had to do with separating the square roots but I wasn't so sure so I decided to ask it as a question.

Comment: @Oliver821: feel free to ask everything you want.

Comment: @Arnoldo in the future yes but for now everything is clear.